# How to detect request timeout errors in dojo? As dojo/request/notify does not detect it

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using `dojo/request/notify` in order to globally detect errors when an issue with a Ajax callis found.

For calling an API I am using `dojo/store/JsonRest`.
When requests have failed `notify` works as expected but in case of timeout `notify` does not work.

I need to detect timeout errors.

- How could achieve this result using dojo?
- Is it possible to set a Timeout option for dojo globally?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813665/set-default-application-wide-timeout-for-xhr-requests-in-dojo-so-that-jsonrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like that dojo does not offer this option out of the box.

I have thought the following solutions:

1. Write a custom version of `dojo/store/JsonRest` which pass a `timeout` value.
2. Monkey patch `dojo/_base/xhr`.
3. Money patch `XMLHttpRequest`.

I have chosen solution 3. here below a code example:

```
 (function (xhr) {
        var send = xhr.send;
        xhr.send = function (data) {
            this.timeout = 5000;
            var hasTimeOut = 'ontimeout' in this;
            if (hasTimeOut) {
                this.ontimeout = function () {
                    throw ('Error XMLHttpRequest timeout.');
                };
            }
            return send.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050071/how-to-set-up-a-timeout-and-ontimeout-for-xmlhttprequest).

Comment: Personally I found option 1 cleaner and less error prone ;)

Comment: Just a suggestion: what about changing `dojo/store/JsonRest` and creating a pull request on dojo github ? That feature could be handy for many people

Comment: @ben thanks for sharing. The problem with option 1 is that does not apply to other modules like dojo/request and the idea was to have a timeout option globally this means covering all module which make requests. Another issue with solution 1 is what you need keep update custom version of JsonRest. this means if bugs are found in the original version I need to merge them on by "custom" JsonRest. Alternatively do you think is possible to monkey patch JsonRest in a reasonable amount of time? By the way I like the idea of a pull request on dojo github ;)

Comment: if you look at `dojo/store/JsonRest`, all methods doing an xhr call have an argument `option`. Best would be to pass the timeout in this arguments. Something like this should work fine: https://gist.github.com/ben8p/eae98b9412b5916faa9753a3b70ac8fa (search for `timeout`). You can probably make a pullrequest out of it