# How to set up a timeout and ontimeout for XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

At the moment I am using a similar code visible below to set a specific value for `timeout` when creating an instance of `XMLHttpRequest`.
I also set a function for `ontimeout` which will be executed when event is fired.

I would like to know if it is possible to set a `timeout` value globally for any `XMLHttpRequest` and a global function when `ontimeout` is called.

I am aware I could use a factory for `XMLHttpRequest` which could set `timeout` and `ontimeout` automatically on each instance created but I would like to know if a different approach exists.

Notes: I am looking for a solution based on vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery or other libraries) and I am targeting only Chrome and FireFox latest version.

Any idea is welcome thanks.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/server', true);
xhr.timeout = 2000;  
xhr.onload = function () {};   
xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {
    // do smt here
}; 
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Is your code wrapped in `common` function ? If yes, You could make use of `||`, `xhr.timeout = PassedArgument || 2000;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least three options:

1. Encapsulate your use of `XMLHttpRequest` in your own function. That lets you apply these sorts of things in that function. The fact your code uses the function makes it perfectly clear what's going on. For instance:

   ```
   function createXHR() {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.timeout = 2000;  
       xhr.addEventListener("timeout", function(e) {
           // ...
       });
       return xhr;
   }
   ```
2. Override `XMLHttpRequest` with your own version. **I do not recommend doing this**, but sometimes if you need to integrate with code that uses `XMLHttpRequest` directly, you may feel you need to do it. Example:

   ```
   (function() {
       var realXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
       XMLHttpRequest = function fakeXMLHttpRequest() {
           realXMLHttpRequest.apply(this, arguments);
           this.timeout = 2000;  
           this.addEventListener("timeout", function(e) {
               // ...
           });
       };
       XMLHttpRequest.prototype = realXMLHttpRequest.prototype;
   })();
   ```

   Again, **I do not recommend it**, but it's possible.

   You've said below that the one above doesn't work for you. If it doesn't, it's because the `XMLHttpRequest` implementation you're using is making life difficult. This workaround will work:

   ```
   (function() {
       var realXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
       XMLHttpRequest = function fakeXMLHttpRequest(arg) {
           var xhr;
           if (typeof arg !== "undefined") {
               // Some implementations allow for a non-standard argument, support them
               xhr = new realXMLHttpRequest(arg);
           } else {
               // Normal case
               xhr = new realXMLHttpRequest();
           }
           xhr.timeout = 2000;  
           xhr.addEventListener("timeout", function(e) {
               // ...
           });
           return xhr;
       };
       XMLHttpRequest.prototype = realXMLHttpRequest.prototype;
   })();
   ```

   That works even though you call it with `new XMLHttpRequest` because the way the `new` operator works is that it creates an object and calls the function with that object as `this`, and then the result of `new` is that object **unless** the function returns a different non-`null` object, as the one above does.

   Did I mention **I do not recommend this**? ;-)
3. Use a library that already does #1 for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time, using option 2 I get the following error: dojo.js:1287 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'XMLHttpRequest': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function. Example https://jsfiddle.net/qa0ewa49/

Comment: Do you think the following monkey patch is correct? Thanks for your time on this. https://jsfiddle.net/9417y5py/

Comment: @GibboK: If you're getting that error, that particular `XMLHttpRequest` implementation is being a pain. I've edited above. Yes, that `send` version looks right, although I don't advocate `onxyz` handlers.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code. I think that I will go using send monkey patch as I need add some additional trace logic not mentioned in my question there. Anyway... I am glad to accept your answer :) thanks fore your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to monkey path `XMLHttpRequest` using the following code.

```
  (function (xhr) {
        var send = xhr.send;
        xhr.send = function (data) {
            this.timeout = 5000;
            var hasTimeOut = 'ontimeout' in this;
            if (hasTimeOut) {
                this.ontimeout = function () {
                    throw ('Error XMLHttpRequest timeout.');
                };
            }
            return send.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);
```